# Sharepoint 2010 not searching content across files

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Having made sure that all the proper indexing options are set, my dev install of SP2010 is still not searching the content of word docs, only titles. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Does your crawler account has sufficient permission to access the file attached to the list item ? Are you crawling your site as a SharePoint site or as a web site (in that case you need to make sure that you have link(s) pointing to the document(s).

Don't you have robots.txt file a the root of your web application that might have exclusions rules preventing the content to be properly crawled ?

If you really want to know what's happening when the crawler is doing it's job, you can install fiddler on your dev machine and change the proxy settings of your search service application to the one created by fiddler. Doing so will allow you to check in real time what url / content is currently being crawled and the http status code that are being returned to diagnose permissions / content issue.

Hope it helped.